Universal approach to connect logic to user Interface for CLI and GUI in C#
I need to write a desktop app in C# that will do some business logic.
For now only CLI is needed as the app needs to be provided ASAP and will be used mainly by technical staff but in the future GUI will be required.
Logic will be written in .NET 8 and will be placed in Class Library project.
CLI is the second project and the future GUI will be a third project (I do not know if it will be WPF or MAUI app right now). I need an unified way of interacting with the UI so I can simply connect the new GUI to the logic and communicate with it in the same way as with CLI.
And here is what I've came up with right now.
Add such interfaces to the Logic:
public interface IUiRead {
    public string ReadString(string message);
    public bool ReadBool(string message);
    public int ReadInt(string message);
    public double ReadDouble(string message);
}

public interface IUiWrite {
    public void Write(string message);
    public void WriteSuccess(string message);
    public void WriteWarning(string message);
    public void WriteError(string message);
    public void WriteProgress(double percentage);
}

This is quite simple and can be easily implemented in CLI and I think can also be implemented in GUI as well. WriteProgress is intended to update progress bar, Write will display some normal information to console or some TextBlock (append), while other methods will show communicates ending task that will be displayed as Dialogs in GUI.
Is such approach valid?
